# Import of excel in odoo on Ubuntu 14.04 - not working

Tags: excel, import, odoo, odoo-9

When I tried to import an excel file in odoo from Windows it worked perfectly. But when tried this from Ubuntu machine it didn't work. It showed me this error

**"import preview failed due to: Unable to load "xlsx" file requires Python module "xlrd >= 0.8"**.

Here's the screen shot

[image: Here's the screen shot]

Comment: What about the error description right there on that page?  Did you check that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that you need a python library "xlrd" in order to load this xlsx file. So make sure that you have installed [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.2) python library in your openerp ubuntu machine.

There's another way mentioned in odoo forum how you can installed it. Here it is

First you have to download the package from:

[pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.2)

Find the folder "xlrd" inside the download, copy it to "OpenERP\Server\"

Restart your server.

Comment: If you using odoo 10 or odoo 11 follow as per the answer of @ian thomson

Answer (score 3):

For Odoo 10, you need to install XLRD which is version 1.0.0 currently.

```
sudo -H pip install xlrd
```

The -H will take care of any error messages regarding the user environment.

Then depending on your system, you **MUST** restart your odoo instance, or it will not recognize that XLRD is installed.

Hope it helps. It just worked for me with Odoo 10 on Ubuntu 16.04